# Self-implemented thread-safe string buffer in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is this piece of code considered as thread-safe?
When I consume the buffer, it will crash sometimes and i think it is contributed to data-racing problems, is there any problem with this implementation?

TSByteBuf.cpp

```
#include "TSByteBuf.h"

int TSByteBuf::Read(byte* buf, int len)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (isBusy.load())
        {
            //Sleep(10);
        }else
        {
            isBusy.store(true);
            int dByteGet = m_buffer.sgetn((char*) buf, len);
            isBusy.store(false);
            return dByteGet;
        }

    }
}

int TSByteBuf::Write(byte* buf, int len)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (isBusy.load())
        {
            //Sleep(10);
        }else
        {
            isBusy.store(true);
            int dBytePut = m_buffer.sputn((char*) buf, len);
            isBusy.store(false);
            return dBytePut;
        }
    }
}
```

TSByteBuf.h

```
#ifndef TSBYTEBUF_H
#define TSBYTEBUF_H

#include <sstream>
#include <atomic>

typedef unsigned char byte;

class TSByteBuf
{
public:
    std::stringbuf m_buffer;
    //bool Write(byte* buf, int len);
    //bool Read(byte* buf, int len);
    int Write(byte* buf, int len);
    int Read(byte* buf, int len);

protected:
    std::atomic<bool> isBusy;
};

#endif
```

Comment: You don't appear to set `isBusy` to true anywhere.

Comment: omg that's a silly bug. But the buffer is still corrupted after adding `isBusy.store(true);` right before modifying the buffer

Comment: I'm sure it's far from the only problem, but here's one: You do nothing to tie the load and the store together. Between the atomic load in the `if` and the `store(true)` in the `else` branch, context switches can occur. Given that you made such an elementary mistake, I suggest you stop trying to re-implement perfectly fine concurrency primitives (such as mutexes). There's probably nothing to be gained anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There's a race between the threads trying to set the `isBusy` variable. With `std::atomic<>`, loads and stores are guaranteed to be atomic, but there's a time windows between those two operations in the code. You need to use a different set of functions that provide the two atomically. See [compare_exchange](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange).

You can make your life easier by using the tools offered by the C++ standard library. To make sure only one thread accesses the given area (has an exclusive access) at a time, you can use `std::mutex`. Further you can use `std::lock_guard`, which will automatically lock (and unlock with the end of the scope) the mutex for you.

```
int TSByteBuf::Read(byte* buf, int len)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
  // do your thing, no need to unlock afterwards, the guard will take care of it for you
}
```

The `mutex` variable needs to be shared between the threads, make it a member variable of the class.

There's an alternative to using `std::mutex` by creating your own locking mechanism if you want to make sure the thread never goes to sleep. As pointed out in the comments, you probably don't need this and the usage of `std::mutex` will be fine. I'm keeping it here just for a reference.

```
class spin_lock {
 public:
  spin_lock() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}

  void lock() {
    while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
      ;
  }

  void unlock() { flag.clear(std::memory_order_release); }

 private:
  std::atomic_flag flag;
};
```

Notice the use of the more lightweight `std::atomic_flag`. Now you can use the class like this:

```
int TSByteBuf::Read(byte* buf, int len)
{
  std::unique_lock<spin_lock> lg(spinner);
  // do your thing, no need to unlock afterwards, the guard will take care of it for you
}
```

Comment: Next question: Why would one use such a class instead of `std::mutex`?

Comment: The OP seems to be interested in a spinning solution. `std::mutex` might spin at first, but will eventually go to sleep.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, it just shifts it: Why should OP prefer a spinning solution? Why would they want to? Besides, I would not read too much into the fact that OP's example is spinning (with regular sleeping, mind you) it's just as likely that was just the simplest lock "emulation" they could think of. OP has already demonstrated not being a concurrency expert.

Answer (score 1):

> *"is there any problem with this implementation?"*

One problem I spot, is that`std::atomic<bool> isBusy;` wouldn't replace a `std::mutex` for locking concurrent access to `m_buffer`. You never set the value to `true`.

But even if you do so (as seen from your edit), `store()` and `load()` operations for the `isBusy` value don't form a lock to protect access to `m_buffer` in whole. Thread context switches may occur in between.

Comment: I try to use isBusy to simulate locking. When an operation (either read or write) is being executed, it will first guarantee the buffer is not busy, and then carry out the corresponding operation. I'm new to multi-threading programs so i'm not so sure if my concept is correct.

Comment: @Alvin As delnan pointed out in his comment, you never seem to set the value to `true`. Thus it can't provide replacement for a mutex.

Comment: Yeh but the buffer is still corrupted after setting the value to true.
Is it because `isBusy.load(); isBusy.store(true);` together is not atomic? which means that the writer thread may read the isBusy after the reader thread checking the isBusy flag but before setting isBusy to be true

Comment: @Alvin _"Is it because isBusy.load(); isBusy.store(true); together is not atomic?"_ Most probably. The `std::atomic<>` only provides that accessing the held value is thread safe.